# Cocos2d V3 issue with texture parameters

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, textures

I've been following a [tutorial for creating textures using cocos2d v2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33266/how-to-create-dynamic-textures-with-ccrendertexture-in-cocos2d-2-x) but I am now using v3 (I have just started learning). I ran into a few issues where v2 code doesn't work in v3 but I managed to get round them. I'm now stuck with just one issue:

```
CCTexParams tp = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT};
```

Error: Use of undeclared identifier 'CCTexParams'

Another comment suggested:

```
Texture2D::TexParams tp = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT};
```

but this doesn't work either (or I'm doing it wrong). Can anyone show me what I need to do?